# find every third instance of specific value in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I have a python list containing hundreds of integers ranging from 1 to 6 inclusive. Essentially, I want to create a function that finds the indexes of every third instance of a 6. Consider this example:

```
l = [5, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 6, 3, 6, 1, 6]

6_finder(l)
> [26, 33]
```

In this example, the third instance of a 6 occurs at index 26, the next third instance of a 6 occurs at index 33.

Any tips on how to approach this? My hunch tells me that a nested loop maybe necessary. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Find all instances of `6` and get every `3`<sup>rd</sup>.*

```
l = [5, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 6, 3, 6, 1, 6]

res = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == 6][2::3]
print(res)
```

which prints

```
[26, 33]
```

> **Explanation**<sup>@BrettBeatty</sup>**:**
>
> Iterating over `enumerate` yields both an `index` and a `value`. The list comprehension then uses the `value` to check if it's `6` and if so, returns the `index`. Those collected indexes are then sliced, beginning at the third element (`index` 2) with a step of 3.

---

Generally, you can neatly pack this all in a function that returns a list with the index of every `k`<sup>th</sup> instance of `n`:

```
def get_index_of_kth_n(lst, n, k=1):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == n][k-1::k]
```

which also handles *corner-cases* such as:

- `lst` passed is empty
- `n` does not appear in `lst`
- `n` appears less than `k` times in `lst`

In all the above cases, an empty list (`[]`) is returned.
Negative `k` values are not supported.

Comment: Just to explain what this does: iterating `enumerate` yields both an index and a value. The list comprehension then uses the value to check that it's `6` and if so yields the index. That list comprehension returns a list of indices, which is then sliced beginning at the third element (index 2) with a step of 3--returning a list or slice with only every third index.

Answer (score 0):

let me know if it does not work for you

```
import numpy as np
sixes = np.where(l=6)
l_sixes = l[sixes]
for i in range(len(3,l_sixes,3)):
    print (l_sixes)
```

Comment: you mean `for i in range(..`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, which is bit more generic:

```
l = [5, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 6, 3, 6, 1, 6]

def val_finder(arr, val):
    res = []
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        if arr[i] == val:
            res.append(i)
    return res

vals = val_finder(l, 6)
print(vals)
print(vals[2::3])
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a function that does the trick.

```
In [13]: def get_every_3rd_instance(mylist, item):
    ...:     count = 0
    ...:     idx_list = []
    ...:     for idx, i in enumerate(mylist):
    ...:         if i == item:
    ...:             count += 1
    ...:             if count == 3:
    ...:                 idx_list.append(idx)
    ...:                 count = 0
    ...: 
    ...:     return idx_list

In [14]: get_every_3rd_instance(l, 6)
Out[14]: [26, 33]
```